Need clarity about EM wave generation
The question may seems very simple. If Electric current is accelerated through a wire, the charges (accelerated) produce Magnetic field. If we say electric current has frequency $\omega$, the magnetic field produced also has frequency $\omega$.

Does this case produce EM wave around it ?
If yes, to quest.1, how it (EM wave) has both electric and magnetic field perpendicular to each other?


(Since the electric current only produce Magnetic field around it alone and how electric part included in it) Give clarity about this concept.


First, consider a simple dipole antenna. In its immediate vicinity it produces an electric field from end to end, and magnetic fields in circles around its axis. These fields are pretty close to perpendicular to each other. If you see it differently, please clarify by editing your question post.
Second, remember that antennas produce both near-field and far-field patterns. The near field component is basically whatever fields you might expect from the geometry of the antenna and the signal driving it. Near field components don't radiate, they're found only near the antenna. The far field is the component that actually matches with what a radiating wave must be and carries energy away from the antenna location.
The point is, not all the field produced by the antenna actually is a radiating wave --- some of it is near-field fields that don't propagate away from the antenna.

Since the electric current only produce Magnetic field around it alone and how electric part included in it

If we're talking about a dipole, the oscillating currents also move charge around. Sometimes they put more negative charge at one end of the antenna and positive charge at the other, and sometimes vice versa. This separation of charges produces electric field between the ends of the antenna.
If we're talking about a loop antenna, then we do, as you suggest, typically analyze it as being a current driven antenna. It produces a magnetic field through the loop. But remember from Maxwell (or rather, from Faraday) that changing magnetic fields produce electric fields. So even if the current in the antenna only produces a magnetic field, that magnetic field itself (as it oscillates) can produce an electric field.

@Thephoton-'In its immediate vicinity it produces an electric field from end to end' - is this mean the flowing current through wires has Electric field from end to end? - because I Am just asking about wires carrying Current, not about any antenna

@RajeshR, 1. It has positive charge at one end and negative charge at the other (oscillating which end is which) --- those charges produce electric field between them. 2. If your wire is radiating then it is acting as an antenna whether you intended it to or not.

Oh, yes. I understand your point about antenna. Ok , then can I take the answer to question 1 as yes?

@RajeshR, yes, it will radiate. How much it will radiate depends on factors like the separation from the return path, length of the wire, presence of other conductive objects nearby, etc.

So far for your time, thanks@ the photon. You said- 'even if the current in the antenna only produces a magnetic field, that magnetic field itself (as it oscillates) can produce an electric field'. How it's possible?

@RajeshR, Faraday's Law of Induction.

I say in steps, let's check this -
From Electric current E, to magnetic field M(effect). So this effect further produce another Electric field É? or E= É.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I searched about antenna (from Niels nielson's response) , but it gives that 'the accelerating charges produce EM wave only if they oscillate like dipole'  - this statement makes the answer to question 1 -is not true always

@Rajesh, Fourier analysis tells us we can break down any time-varying signal into sinusoidal components. So unless the wire is carrying exactly the same current from the dawn of time to the end of time, it has some current components that "oscillate like a dipole". Since no electronic device was ever made before the dawn of time and kept running until the end of time, every device ever made has radiated at least slightly.

Well Said.. I get that the point i.e., the accelerating charges produce EM wave atleast slightly, even if it is moving in a straight. But it may emit (far field) effectively if the setup is in dipole manner.

@RajeshR, there's a whole engineering discipline (electromagnetic compliance engineering) to work out how much an unintended radiator might radiate, and provide rules for circuit designers to minimize the radiation. A dipole is one way of making a somewhat efficient radiator. A loop can also be fairly efficient --- and every circuit is a loop, so one of the most important ways of avoiding radiation is to keep the loop area small relative to the wavelength you're trying not to radiate.

The charges produce an electric field all the time, even when they are not moving. This means that electric charges sloshing back and forth along a wire will produce a mixture of time-varying E and M fields continuously.

@nielsNielsen- Electric field In what direction? Some answers from Google says it's along parallel and other as no field around it

@RajeshR, search on dipole antenna field and you will see the directions of both fields as time varies.

Yes, I checked about it.
